# CSS - Unwanted padding on left and top

Tags: css

I am making a stupid site in the vein of sites on [theuselessweb.com](http://theuselessweb.com). (Warning: strange audio on pages for every link henceforth.) However, I am running into an issue: I have a vignette effect on the site that serves as a background, and in [this jsFiddle](http://tinyurl.com/ao7j42p), where I did all my work, it looks perfect. However, when I [upload it to my webserver](http://www.suchipi.com/oniichan.html) to test for real, it doesn't behave in either Chrome or Firefox: There is an unwanted space between the background color and the vignette effect on the top and left sides of the page. What is causing this? How can I get rid of it?

Edit: Since I received an answer, this has been resolved. As such, the link to my webserver above no longer has the issue.

Comment: Jsfiddle adds a CSS reset by default that is incorrectly labeled as "normalized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser defines some different margins or paddings to elements by default. In your case, there is a margin to the body-element.

Change this in your css and you are fine.

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #666666;
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking your css for something like this:

```
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

if the problem persist, probably is because some of your lower classes in CSS are overriding the style